# Boolean vs Int in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, boolean, int

I always assumed that booleans were more efficient than ints at storing an on/off value - considering that's their reason for existence. I recently decided to check if this is true with the help of jsperf, and it came up with some contrary results!

http://jsperf.com/bool-vs-int

Here is the first test I tried. Toggling the value of the on/off switch. On Chrome it's significantly faster to do this using 1/0, but on firefox it's slightly faster to do this using bool. Interesting.

http://jsperf.com/bool-vs-int-2

And here's the second test I tried. Using them in a conditional. This appears to have significant advantage for ints as opposed to bools, up to 70% faster to use 1/0 instead of booleans - on both firefox and chrome. Wtf?

I guess my question is, am I doing something wrong? Why are ints so much better at boolean's job? Is the only value of using bools clarity, or am I missing something important?

Comment: You say "only value" as if clarity weren't of premium importance!

Comment: Oh, and with IE8 there's no significant difference.
@Malvolio: 1/0 toggles are pretty clear too! The only theoretically confusing part is the x=1-x toggle, and the performance boosts seem worth the explanatory comment.

Comment: Interesting but one test set is missing: if(a==true) bluh(); if(b==false) bluh();

Comment: At over one hundred million operations per second, I don't believe that you will ever see this as a performance bottleneck in real world code.

Comment: Interesting, this may have something to do with operating system. I just ran these tests on Mac Firefox and Chrome, Bool was significantly faster on all tests other than Chrome boolvsint2 which was definitely quite a bit slower...

Comment: Well, on my Win7 system, Chrome blew IE9 and FF6 out of the water with speed for test 1, so no surprise there, but Chrome appears to be int biased, FF bool biased, and IE9 is up in the air. (Another sidenote: FF6 was the slowest of the three for these calculations.)

Comment: I added === (rev 6). Results from Android 2.2 (mobile webkit) appear closer to expected.

Comment: OP, tell me you're kidding.  You are not seriously planning to make your code less clear in the hopes of saving tens of nanoseconds by exploiting temporary idiosyncrasies in the current implementations of some browsers for a program where performance isn't even important?  If you were writing graphics-card software or weather simulation, *maybe*.  Otherwise, tell your language what you want it to do and trust the language implementers to optimize the results.

Comment: Dude, this oddity blows my mind. +1 for even thinking about it.

Comment: @Malvolio I don't think he'll be implementing it; he probably just wants to know why int-toggling works better than bool-toggling. I know I do.

Comment: @Edwin -- I was responding to the OP's comment "the performance boosts seem worth the explanatory comment."  His research seems useful *to Javascript engine implementers* but not to Javascript programmers like me (except to say, "Booleans take less than 10ns to evaluate.  Don't worry about performance.")

Comment: @Malvolio is correct in that this information is mostly an interesting oddity to javascript programmers - the performance boost really is quite irrelevant, because even the most inefficient code will be near instant at these speeds. Seems to be the way programming is going these days - you can afford to be lax on optimization because hardware is getting better and better. I think that's pretty cool. Makes code more readable, anyway.

Comment: @Thristhart -- depends on how you define "this days".  Back in the early seventies, Knuth and Hoare were noticing the fact that intuitive performance improvements that programmers were making *didn't help* and would make the programs harder to actually improve.  So yes, "Since the end of the punch-card era, you can afford to be lax on optimization because hardware is getting better and better."  Which *is* pretty cool.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Disclaimer, I can only speak for Firefox, but I guess Chrome is similar.

First example (http://jsperf.com/bool-vs-int):

1. **The Not operation**
   JägerMonkey (Spidmonkey's JavaScript methodjit) inlines the check for boolean first and then just xors, which is really fast (We don't know the type of a/b, so we need to check the type).
   The second check is for int, so if a/b would be a int this would be a little bit slower.
   [Code](http://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/file/7c905a200bcc/js/src/methodjit/FastOps.cpp#l768)
2. **The Subtract operation.**
   We again don't know the type of c/d. And again you are lucky we are going to assume ints and inline that first. But because in JavaScript number operations are specified to be IEEE 754 doubles, we need to check for overflow. So the only difference is "sub" and a "conditional jump" on overflow vs. plain xor in case 1.
   [Code](http://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/file/7c905a200bcc/js/src/methodjit/FastArithmetic.cpp#l433)

Second example:
(I am not 100% sure about these, because I never really looked at this code before)

1. and 3. **The If**. 
   We inline a check for boolean, all other cases end up calling a function converting the value to a boolean.
   [Code](http://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/file/7c905a200bcc/js/src/methodjit/FastOps.cpp#l920)
2. **The Compare and If**.
   This one is a really complex case from the implementation point of view, because it was really important to optimize equality operations. So I think I found the right code, that seems to suggest we first check for double and then for integers.
   And because we know that the result of a compare is always a boolean, we can optimize the `if` statement.
   [Code](http://hg.mozilla.org/integration/mozilla-inbound/file/7c905a200bcc/js/src/methodjit/FastArithmetic.cpp#l1411)

*Followup* I dumped the generated machine code, so if you are still interested, [here you go](https://gist.github.com/1179203).

Overall this is just a piece in a bigger picture. If we knew what kind of type the variables had and knew that the subtraction won't overflow then we could make all these cases about equally fast.
These efforts are being made with [IonMonkey](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/05/ionmonkey) or v8's Crankshaft. This means you should avoid optimizing based of this information, because:

1. it's already pretty fast
2. the engine developers take care of optimizing it for you
3. it will be even faster in the future.

Comment: One of the best answers to anything on stack overflow... How does this not have more upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

your test was a bit off due to the definition of "function" and "var" and the call for the function. The cost to define function and variables and calling them will differ from engine to engine. I modified your tests, try to re-run with your browsers (note that IE was off because the first run was weird but consecutive runs were as expected where bool is fastest): http://jsperf.com/bool-vs-int-2/4

Comment: Guys, if it ain't an answer, don't post it as an answer.

Comment: defining the function and var are done *outside* the tests, and calling the function is done an equal number of times *per* test. Variations between JS implementations doesn't seem relevant since this is meant to be a comparison between the different tests, not the different browsers.

Comment: Gah, a boolean compare seems to take 1.2 ns.  So if we got a 10% improvement, 8 *billion* repetitions would save one second.

Comment: @Edwin, this was an answer.  The question was "Am I doing something wrong?" (really, check the post) and the answer, apparently, is "Yes".

Comment: @Malvolio Whoops; I was focusing on the last two questions.

Comment: @patrick the cost of calling a function (depending on how you defined it) will slightly differ from engine to engine. "Variations between JS implementations doesn't seem relevant" I do not agree with you on that, take a quick look at a loop improvement that i did some time ago: http://jsperf.com/amoldavsky/10 every engine has it's own quirks

Comment: @Assaf Moldavsky: But there you're comparing different means of iterating an Array, which happens to call a function. My point was that between the tests that OP presented, there was no difference in the function being invoked, nor in the means by which it was invoked. The only difference was the expression presented to the `if` statement. Therefore any overhead presented by the function invocation would be an equal amount of overhead in each test.

Comment: @patrick: I totally understand your point and it is absolutely valid but it not always true, take a look here: http://jsperf.com/amoldavsky/19 Different engines will process these blocks differently, you would expect that it will be proportional but it doesn't have to be. Therefore, in order to illuminate that out of the equation I simply minimized the scope to the core operations without additional code which effects we are not sure about.

Comment: @Assaf Moldavsky: Yes, and your test more accurately tested the direct difference. Browsers that compile the JS will likely optimize away code that doesn't really do anything. [Here's an update](http://jsperf.com/amoldavsky/20) of your last test. I changed it so that the `test()` function returns a `Math.random()`, and assigns it to a variable. Suddenly the result is more proportionate. Going back to the original example from OP, it reflects a more real world scenario because it involves variable scope traversal. But you're absolutely right, different browsers will behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but in the second test it does
`if(a) bluh();`
vs
`if(c == 1) bluh();`

maybe `c==1` is faster because you're comparing a value with one with the same type
but if you do `if(a)` then js need to check if the value evaluates to true, not just if it is true...

That could be the reason...

Maybe we need to test
`if(c==1)`
vs
`if(a===true)` with three =

Comment: Guys, if it ain't an answer, don't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the choice would be based on API usage. Always return that which is most useful. If I use secondary code, I'd favor methods that return booleans. This probably makes the code ready to be chained. The alternative is to provide overloaded methods.

Answer (score 0):

Diggin' deep here. Regarding performance, I'm still unsure (this is why I found this thread) if booleans vs 0/1 is faster when computing and it still seems heavily browser-dependent. But take into account, that in extremely huge datasets the data has to be downloaded by the user first anyway:
"true" and "false" obv take up 4 or 5 characters respectively, whereas 0 and 1 are only 1 character. So it might save you a little bit of bandwidth at least, so less time to load and only after that is it up to the client's browser and hardware how to deal with those types, which seems pretty much negligible.

As a little bonus and to actually contribute something, since (I think?) no one mentioned it here, if you are going with the 0 and 1 approach, instead of using if-statements you can use bitwise operations to toggle between them, which should be pretty fast:

```
x=0;
x^=1; // 1
x^=1; // 0
```

This is the equivalence to using this toggle for booleans:

```
x=false;
x=!x; // true
x=!x; // false
```