# Javascript - efficient way to store/work with my large object list

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, object

I'm working on creating an online guide.  It will survey users, and based on their answers, output a list that best suits their needs.

I'm about to assemble a large list of objects and properties, but before I spend too much time on it, I'd like to address some concerns:

To give you an idea of what I'm going for, here's an example using an interactive guide to finding a travel destination:

Questions for the user:

```
<form name="equator" action="">
<p>What side of the equator do you want to visit?</p>
<input type="radio" name="equator" value="north">North<br />
<input type="radio" name="equator" value="south">South<br />
</form>
<br />
<form name="english" action="">
<p>Does English need to be the first language?</p>
<input type="radio" name="english" value="yes">Yes<br />
<input type="radio" name="english" value="no">No<br />
</form>
<br />
<form name="beach" action="">
<p>Do you want a nearby beach?</p>
<input type="radio" name="beach" value="yes">Yes<br />
<input type="radio" name="beach" value="maybe">Maybe<br />
<input type="radio" name="beach" value="no">No<br />
</form>
```

The following is the way I plan to create the object list:

```
destinations = [

{
    name: "Moscow", equator: "north", english: "no", beach: "no"
},

{
    name: "Lima", equator: "south", english: "no", beach: "no"
},

{
    name: "Nantucket", equator: "north", english: "yes", beach: "yes"
},

]
```

In the project I'm working on, the object list will actually number in the hundreds, with up-to two dozen properties.  That said, here are my concerns (in case it affects your answers, I should note that my experience with Javascript only dates back about two weeks):

- Is my example above an efficient way to store an object list, considering it's potential size?  If not, can you suggest something better?
- My experience with Javascript so far has consisted of slogging through "w3schools" tutorials and creating mini projects to get a feel for the language...so far every script I've created has processed instantaneously.  Taking my project--as outlined--into consideration, should I be concerned about any performance hits?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Shouldn't `english` and `beach` be booleans?

Comment: Off topic: please read through [w3fools.com](http://w3fools.com/)

Comment: "hundreds" is not a consequential number to any modern device for the type of object you've provided/described.  Worry about functionality before efficiency.

Comment: Using _one_ form and jQuery all you need is a mere one liner `$('form').serializeArray()` to get your structure.

Comment: Dang, I didn't realize w3schools is such a joke...I need to do some research next time before I waste two weeks studying from an online resource...thanks for the alternate resources, folks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*Arrays*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [*Objects*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) are good at storing data like this. In JavaScript, an *Array* is just a specific type of *Object*.

What you should think about is how can you make the data as "basic" as possible; i.e. if an answer has only two answers, consider using the Boolean `true` or `false`. If it is more, then the next stop should be integers `0`, `1`, .. [In some cases in JavaScript integers work more efficiently than Boolean values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7221963/1615483). The idea I'm trying to convey is it's normally more efficient to only use a string when you actually need a string, e.g. for a name.

One of the best resources to learn JavaScript is probably [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript), w3schools is not a good resource.

Answer (score 1):

Like Joseph Silber said in the comments, you'll want to change the types on `english` and `beach` to boolean, IE: `true` or `false.`

As for storing your objects, I like plugins, in theory. Take a look at the tutorials on [www.knockoutjs.com](http://www.knockoutjs.com). First they'll show you how to create objects with `name`, `equator`, `english`, and `beach` properties. It will also show you a lot of cool things you can do with that data that'll improve user experience.

Edit: Sorry, to directly answer your question, look into JSON. You're on the right track already, I'm just not sure how you're generating your array.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback, folks.  Clearly, I have a lot to learn...doesn't sound like I have much to worry about here, other than my own shortcomings as a noob "programmer".  Thanks again!

Comment: You're doing fine @user1965279. My biggest concern about your post is the absence of a proper user name.

Comment: Just changed my username to something more "proper"... :)