# Why does babel convert "true" to "!0"

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I have inspected my converted code and i have seen that `true` is converted to `!0`

Example:

```
 let obj = {
    loading: true
 }
```

Is converted to:

```
 let obj = {
    loading: !0
 }
```

Why is that? Is it because of performance reason or because something else?

Comment: For minifaction. https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans

Comment: You are probably using [_babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans_](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans). As far as I know it's only in due of reducing bundle size.

Comment: You can also read up on this boolean vs int thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7221963/boolean-vs-int-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For minifaction, ie: smaller bundle size. See also: [babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-minify-booleans)