# Javascript why is "true === true" slower then "true === !0"

Tags: javascript, performance, benchmarking

I found out that babel is compiling true and false to `!0` and `!1` in some situations. I made some benchmarks online and found out that it seems to be faster to compare "true === !0" then compare "true === true". Why is this the case ?

Example code which was transpiled by babbel

```
 Object.defineProperty(e, t, {
        configurable: !1,
        enumerable: !0,
        get: o
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Those results are each within the large +- confidence interval of the other as printed alongside the ops/second; you *don't* know that one is faster than the other.  Probably because you tested on a noisy / not-idle system.

Comment: That benchmark is absolutely meaningless. https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61617527/why-does-babel-convert-true-to-0

Comment: the compile time is longer, the run time should be equal.

Comment: Adding to @PeterCordes comment: that's why both of them say "Fastest"!